# How to connect the socket.io in node.js (typescript )?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, socket.io

`GET http://localhost:3001/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NX0bUXk 404 (Not Found)`

getting this type of error
actually from angular, the socket.io is connection to node which is written in ts

In node to create server

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server).listen(server);
initialize(io);
```

i'm using this lines to create the server and use the socketUrl in angular environment file as
`http://localhost:3001/`